Docker containers doesnt start after docker-compose - kafka , zookeeper and debezium
Iam new to docker, I have utilized almost 7.7 GB of my 8 GB memory. I have to runkafka-ui , schema registry, kafka , zookeeper , debzium , pyspark for an etl process. I couldnt run all of them simultaneously. I tried including ticktime too in my yaml file, that continuously restarts the services. What may be the error, The image attached shows the docker desktop cpu and memory utilization ? I would be thankful if anybody could help me with this...
yaml file :
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.3
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.5.3
    depends_on: [zookeeper]
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9991
    ports:
      - 9092:9092

  debezium:
    image: debezium/connect:2.7.3.Final
    environment:
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      GROUP_ID: 1
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_configs
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_offsets
      KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: false
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: false
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
    depends_on: [kafka]
    ports:
      - 8083:8083

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.3
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zookeeper:2181
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://schema-registry:8081
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on: [zookeeper, kafka]

  pyspark:
    image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - ./pyspark:/home/jovyan/work
      - ./postgresql-42.7.4.jar:/usr/share/java/postgresql-42.7.3.jar
      - ./mssql-jdbc-12.8.1.jre8.jar:/usr/share/java/mssql-jdbc-12.8.1.jar
    environment:
      - PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS=--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.0 pyspark-shell
    depends_on:
      - kafka

  kafka-ui1:
    container_name: kafka-ui1
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      DYNAMIC_CONFIG_ENABLED: 'true'
    depends_on:
      - kafka

debezium.json file :

{
  "name": "connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "database.hostname": "host.docker.internal",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "xxxx",
    "database.password": "yyyy",
    "database.dbname": "zzzz",
    "database.server.name": "postgres",
    "table.include.list": "table1",
    "slot.name": "slottt",
    "topic.prefix": "postgres",
    "topic.creation.default.partitions": "6",
    "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": "1",
    "transforms": "PartitionRouting,unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.unwrap.delete.tombstone.handling.mode": "rewrite-with-tombstone",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "transforms.unwrap.add.fields": "table,lsn,ts_ms,op",
    "transforms.unwrap.add.fields.prefix": "",
    "transforms.PartitionRouting.type": "io.debezium.transforms.partitions.PartitionRouting",
    "transforms.PartitionRouting.partition.payload.fields": "change.cityid",
    "transforms.PartitionRouting.partition.topic.num": "6",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "dead_letter_queue"
  }
}

I need to run all these services at once, Will my windows machine support this process ?
Are there ways to configure my wslconfig file to increase cpu usage of the docker container in any way ? What could be the solution for this ?
Startup logs :
kafka:
2024-12-23 13:48:49 exec /etc/confluent/docker/run: exec format error
zookeeper:
2024-12-23 13:48:48 exec /etc/confluent/docker/run: exec format error
debezium:
[org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig]
2024-12-23 13:49:06 2024-12-23 08:19:06,319 WARN   ||  Couldn't resolve server kafka:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka   [org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils]
2024-12-23 13:49:06 2024-12-23 08:19:06,320 ERROR  ||  Stopping due to error   [org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli]
2024-12-23 13:49:06 org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
2024-12-23 13:49:06     at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:541)
